# bottomless tee?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe, tee

I was just playing around in the terminal and I did this:

```
printf 'some string\n' | {
    tee /dev/fd/3 | {
        : && sed 's/some/string/'
    }
} 3>&0
```

I was really surprised when I was met with a screen full of:

```
string string
string string
string string
...
```

It went on pretty much forever. I pared it down some, and to better demonstrate, maybe try this:

```
echo | tee /dev/fd/0 | sed =
```

For me, it presents output like:

```
<num>
#blank
<num+1>
#blank
...
```

And so on. The few times I've tried it by the time I could hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I was at line 200k+. I tried this in `bash`, `dash`, `sh`, and `zsh` and all present the same results.

What is going on there? How are the file-descriptors passing over that `|pipe` between, what I thought were, separate processes? Is this reliable and/or expected behavior? Are there other ways to generate this effect?

For reference:

```
echo '#blank' | {
    uname -r
    readlink -f /dev/fd/0
    tee /dev/fd/0
} | sed '=;5q'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1
3.14.6-1-ARCH
2
/proc/24925/fd/pipe:[5851017]
3
#blank
4
#blank
5
#blank
```

Comment: On `zsh`, it does not work for me - `$ZSH_VERSION 5.0.2`
`$ echo | tee /dev/fd/0 | sed =`
`tee: /dev/fd/0: Text file busy`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - It works for me in `zsh` - and everything else - but it didn't *used* to. This is new, which is why I was taken by surprise. Believe me, I've encountered that very same *text file busy* error more times than I can count. I *believe* this has a lot less to do with the shell - if anything - than it does with the way the kernel handles `|pipes` and/or the way `tee` does. So it's either a kernel option, a newer kernel feature, or a newer coreutils feature. I'm not sure which. In any case it behaves the same for me in `X` and in the console.

Comment: Interesting; Works for me in bash like you describe, actually. BASH_VERSION: 4.3.11(1)-release on Linux 3.13.0-24.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - That is very interesting, and may invalidate my previous assumption... Thanks very much for the information. I'm going to try to figure out how to test it more thoroughly.

Comment: If I run bash as `bash --norc --noprofile`, I get the error `tee: /dev/fd/0: Text file busy` in bash too. So it's probably related to some shell option or similar.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - well, I don't encounter those problems. I did the same thing you did - I even `exec`ed the process through `env -i` - and it worked everytime. It worked when I also `exec`ed `zsh`, `sh`, and `dash`. I can't understand how the shell interferes for you, but here it's not even a factor. See [this](http://gdriv.es/mikeserv/text/bottomlesstee.txt). I can't understand how any of those shells could share any shell options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/dev/fd/0` is the current process's standard input; `tee` writes its input to both to the file(s) you give it and to stdout. So `tee` is reading a (blank) line, then writing that line to both stdout (`sed`) and its own input, where it reads the line it just wrote, writes it to stdout and its own input, etc., creating an infinite loop of (empty) lines*. The `sed` command just prints the line number and then the line.

```
echo --> tee --> sed
      ^---+
```

* When provided more input than just a simple `echo`, this command will loop over the input, repeating it over and over.

Note: OSX (BSD) doesn't let you write to `/dev/fd/0`, so you can't do this.

Comment: At what point does `tee` start writing over what it reads? For instance `seq 100 | tee /dev/fd/0 | sed 101q` gets `..\n100\n1\n` ...

Comment: @mikeserv It never overwrites its input, it just appends to it. It will basically repeat the provided input over and over.

Comment: Well, that's very cool. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's Linux specific. On linux /dev/fd/x is a symlink to a resource. In this case the resource acts like a named-pipe, so opening /dev/fd/3 in write mode, doesn't duplicate the fd 3 as it would on other systems, but opens (in a difference mode (WR instead of RD)) the pipe, so you get the writing end of the pipe (the other end as that opened on 3).