# Dash equivalent of self-redirection of script output

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, dash, process-substitution

In Bash you can redirect all *future* stdout output of the *currently running* script. For example with this script,

```
exec > >(logger -t my-awesome-script)
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

This will end up in syslog:

```
Oct 26 01:03:16 mybox my-awesome-script[72754]: 1
Oct 26 01:03:16 mybox my-awesome-script[72754]: 2
Oct 26 01:03:16 mybox my-awesome-script[72754]: 3
```

But this is Bash-specific and the naked exec with redirection doesn't seem to work in Dash.

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

How can I make it work in Dash, or possibly in both shells?

Comment: Could you clarify what you need exactly? You can redirect with `>` in dash. I realize you seem to be asking for something else but I can't quite tell what it is.

Comment: @terdon I have expanded the explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do:

```
{ commands
....
} | logger -t my_awesome_script
```

You can do that with any shell.

If you don't like the way it looks, maybe make the script wrap itself in a function.

```
#!/bin/sh
run() if     [ "$run" != "$$" ] || return
      then   sh -c 'run=$$ exec "$0" "$@"' "$0" "$@" |
             logger -t my-awesome-script
      fi
#script-body
run "$@" || do stuff
```

Comment: That last line should be `run ${1+"$@"} || do stuff` so that arguments are retained.

Comment: @AdamKatz - good point, execpt `${1+"$@"}` does nothing `"$@" ` doesnt. It had other problems anyway.

Comment: `"$@"` will pass `""` when there are no arguments while `${1+"$@"}` will pass an empty string when there are no arguments.  This matters tremendously for many programs, as they parse `""` as an empty argument while an (unquoted) empty string would not be interpreted as an argument at all.

Comment: @AdamKatz - a very old Bourne shell might *(and i wouldnt expect to find `dash` on such a system)*, but otherwise `"$@"` is unique in that a zero-args case does not substitute to a null argument for POSIX shells.

Comment: Confirmed.  Nice, I didn't know that part (I cut my teeth on ancient POSIX shells and write code that is still portable to most of them).  Not that I still have access to any old UNIX boxes, so I can't even verify that this is necessary.  It's merely how I was taught waaaay back when.  This is still true for `"$*"` vs `${1+"$*"}` however.

Comment: @AdamKatz - it was actually a bug even in the old bsh and should never have worked like that. It was eventually fixed, but i dunno whether or not it should still be necessary in a Solaris 10, for example. Youre right about $* - it doesnt exhibit the same neat properties of expabsion - its uniqueness onky pertains to the variable contents of its expansion, though it will always be something.in my opinion,  `"${@+is especially cool $@}" `. But not practically very different than the old `${1+”$@"}` workaround after all. If you have a ksh93: `"${1+quoted" not quoted "quoted again}"`

Answer (score 5):

Process substitution is easily simulated with named pipes.

```
mkfifo logger_input
logger -t my_awesome_script < logger_input &
exec > logger_input
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
```

In fact, named pipes are one of the mechanisms (the other being `/dev/fd`) with which process substitution can be implemented in `bash`.

Comment: The most versatile in my opinion: I could use tee to redirect to several streams seamlessly.
Just one thing: do not forget to delete the created logger_input at the end of a script.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible in `dash`. As far as I can tell from its [`man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), it has no support for process substitution.

As a workaround, you could try what [mikserv suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164195/22222), or you can redirect everything to a file, and then after your script is finished (presumably this is in a script), add that file's contents to logger:

```
$ exec > ~/foo/foo.txt
$ ls
$ echo something
$ cat foo/foo.txt | sudo logger -t my-awesome-script
```

Comment: In fact, process substitution - or what other shells call process substitution - is easier in `dash` then other shells. Process substitution just amounts to an argument that points to a `/dev/fd/[num]` link to an anonymous pipe. `dash` does here-documents with anonymous pipes rather than genning temp files as most other shells do. So `cat /dev/fd/3 3<<HEREDOC\n$(get output)\nHEREDOC\n` is not only functionally equivalent, you even get to name the fd yourself. Still, your point is well made about going the other way - you need to open a new fd with `exec` and background a process that reads it.

Comment: @mikeserv: In what sense is `cat /dev/fd/3 3<<HEREDOC\n$(get output)\nHEREDOC\n` "easier" than `cat <(get output)`?

Comment: @mikeserv: It involves plenty of rules to remember; perhaps you have simply grown so used to them that you don't notice.

Comment: @ruakh - well, sure. `< >` shell redirections. basically if you just do two of those you can then pile on the following lines too. But yeah, you have a point - I like here docs. Still, as many things as might require remembering, it's easier when they work universally I think. Then again a lot of people don't have much use for other shells and so it makes no difference to them. I'm just not among them.

Comment: @mikeserv: Not just heredocs, but also `/dev/fd/3` (in that precise form), and the details of what happens to whitespace . . . and for that matter, the fact that this whole approach works at all in Dash, when it doesn't work in other shells that have all of the components, means that the overall approach is a special rule to remember. (This reminds me of attempts to create a simplified English with less vocabulary; they cut out words like *persist*, but they ignore just-as-difficult idioms like *keep on*.)

Comment: @ruakh - it works in all the other shells - it's exactly what process substitution is - it works in any shell. `dash` does it faster because it doesn't need a temp file, but - try `echo|tee -a /dev/fd/0`. Or `4<<SCRIPT . /dev/fd/4\necho $$\nSCRIPT\n` or anything. They're just file links. That's all - it works for any file descriptor. And that's the `<(cmd)` form is silly - it hides a very simple thing like it's magic or something. They're just *not-seekable* files.

Comment: @mikeserv: Re: "it works in any shell": Not true. I tried your original example in Bash, Dash, and Zsh, and it worked only in Dash. (N.B. This was on Cygwin, which is what I had handiest. I can check more typical environments, namely Ubuntu and RHEL5, if desired.) Also, `echo ... | tee -a /dev/fd/0` didn't work in any of the three (`tee: /dev/fd/0: Permission denied`), but that doesn't surprise me; I'm guessing you really meant `echo ... | tee -a /dev/fd/1`, which worked in all of them.

Comment: @ruakh - no, I meant `/dev/fd/0`. The problem in those cases is not the shell - it is the *system*. As I said, `cmd /dev/link [num]<<HD\n$(cmd)\nHD\n` is specific to `[dy]ash` in that in treats the same as `<(cmd)` - which I regard as simpler approach - whereas the other shells use special syntax for either or - and will either gen temp files or pipe files. But `/dev/links` must be supported well on the system. Perhaps this is near-sighted of me - because I tend to work only in Linux. I once [asked about the `tee` thing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137731/52934) if you care.

Comment: @ruakh - also look at chepner's answer here for a possible explanation about why. It's a good one.